# How to hide a password

Tags: passwords, hide

I have an application that uses database. Data about how to connect to the database is stored in a properties file. There you can find server name, database name, username, password, ... I read this file and make a connecton to a database in my program.

How can I "hide" the password, so that someone else would have it hard time to retrieve that password?

Comment: I think that's enough, now, @SperanskyDanil. A mere hint on how to use the search facilities should be sufficient at this point.

Comment: OK, I admit I wasn't clear enough. My application is a desktop applciation that connects to a database running on a different machine. The user is already logged to the machine where the properties file is stored. I want to prevent/make it hard for the user to get to the username and password for the database.